# How to prove this is a self-adjoint operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I have this operator from $H^1_0$ to $H^1_0$ defined by: $$Au(t)=\int_0^1 G(t,s) f(s,u(s))\mathsf ds$$ where $$G(t,s)=\begin{cases} t(1-s), &t\leq s\\s(1-t), &s\leq t.\end{cases}$$

I want to see if $A'(0)$ is self-adjoint, if my calculus are right we have

$$A'(u)[v](t)= \int_0^1G(t,s) f_{u}(s,u(s)) v(s)\mathsf ds $$

Have you an idea please ?

Comment: What is $f$?  In general, it doesn't look like this is even a linear operator.

Comment: It depends on $f$. Please be more specific.

Comment: it depends on $f$ yes and i must make a condition on $f$ such that we obtain that $A'(0)$ is self-adjoint what i have now is that $f$ is $C^1$ @user251257

Comment: @NateEldredge i must find a condition on $f_u(t,0)$ to obtain that $A'(0)$ is self adjoint

Comment: basically, you need $f_u(t,0)$ is constant in $t$...

Comment: @user251257 what is the equality must we have to obtain that $A'(0)$ is selft adjoint ?please

Comment: you need to show $ \langle w, A'(0) v \rangle = \langle A'(0) w, v \rangle$.

Comment: @user251257 yes but what is equal to $<A'(0)w,v>$ please

Comment: the $L^2[0,1]$ inner product, that is $\langle u, v \rangle = \int_0^1 u(t) v(t) \;\mathrm d t$.

Comment: why we don't use the inner product in $H^1_0$ ?

Comment: @user251257 ? 
 
why we don't use the inner product in $H^1_0$

Comment: you are right the $H^1_0$ one. My bad.

Comment: So $<A'(0)w,v>=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^1 G(t,s) f_u(s,u(s)) w(s) ds\right]' v'(t) dt$ i think that this is equal to 0 ?

Comment: @user251257 What do you think about this please

Comment: First, it would be $\langle A'(0)w, v \rangle = \int_0^1 A'(0)w(t)v(t) \,\mathrm d t + \int_0^1 (A'(0)w)'(t)v'(t) \,\mathrm d t$. Secound, why should the last term be zero? Try to compute the first term, notice that $G$ is symmetric. Then, try the second term.

Comment: $<A'(0)w,v>=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^1 G(t,s) f_u(s,u(s)) w(s) ds\right]' v'(t) dt=\int_0^1 [G(t,1)f_u(1,0) w(1)-G(t,0)f_{u}(0,0) w(0)]v'(t) dt$                                 right ?@user251257

Comment: @user251257 please ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R^2$.
Also assume that $f_u(s, 0) := \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(s,0) = c$ for every $s\in[0,1]$.

Notice that $G(t,s) = G(s,t)$ for every $s,t\in[0,1]$.
Thus, for $v,w \in H^1_0$ we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 A'(0)[v](t) w(t) \;\mathrm d t
&= \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 G(t,s)f_u(s,0)v(s) \;\mathrm d s\right) \; w(t) \;\mathrm d t \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 G(t,s) c v(s) w(t) \;\mathrm d s \;\mathrm d t \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 G(s,t) c w(t) v(s)  \;\mathrm d t \;\mathrm d s \\
&= \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 G(s,t) f_u(t,0) w(t) \;\mathrm d t \right) \; v(s) \;\mathrm d s \\
&= \int_0^1 v(s) A'(0)[w](s) \;\mathrm d s.
\end{align}$$
Further, we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (A'(0)[v])'(t) w'(t) \;\mathrm d t
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\left( \int_0^1 G(t,s)f_u(s,0)v(s) \;\mathrm d s\right) \; w'(t) \;\mathrm d t \\
&= \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 \frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(t,s)f_u(s,0)v(s) \;\mathrm d s\right) \; w'(t) \;\mathrm d t \\
&= \int_0^1 \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(t,s) v(s) \;\mathrm d s}_{=:\phi(t)} \; cw'(t) \;\mathrm d t.
\end{align}$$
From
$$\phi'(t) 
= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\int_0^t (-s) v(s) \;\mathrm d s + \int_t^1 (1-s) v(s) \;\mathrm d s \right)
= (-t) v(t) - (1-t) v(t) = -v(t) 
$$ 
follows
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (A'(0)[v])'(t) w'(t) \;\mathrm d t
&= -\int_0^1 c v(t) w'(t) \;\mathrm d t \\
&= \underbrace{-\left. cv(t)w(t) \right|_0^1}_{=0} + \int_0^1 c v'(t) w(t) \;\mathrm d t \\
&= \int_0^1 v'(t) (A'(0)[w])'(t) \;\mathrm d t.
\end{align}$$
That is, $A'(0)$ is self adjoint.

Comment: $\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (A'(0)[v])'(t) w'(t) \;\mathrm d t
&= \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 G_t(t,s)f_u(s,0)v(s) \;\mathrm d s\right)' \; w'(t) \;\mathrm d t 
\end{align}$ no ?

Comment: Either $\int_0^1 G_t(t,s) ...$ or $(\int_0^1 G(t,s) ...)'$. Not both :)

Comment: how do you find that $\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (A'(0)[v])'(t) w'(t) \;\mathrm d t
&= \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 G_t(t,s)f_u(s,0)v(s) \;\mathrm d s\right) \; w'(t) \;\mathrm d t 
\end{align}$

Comment: By dominated convergence, you have $$(A'(0)[v])'(t) = \left( \int_0^1 G(t,s)f_u(s,0)v(s) \;\mathrm d s\right)' = \left( \int_0^1 G_t(t,s)f_u(s,0)v(s) \;\mathrm d s\right). $$

Comment: dominated convergence ???

Comment: differentiation under the integral sign is basically dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: i  just know lebesgue dominated convergence , do you have a reference ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou that's what I meant. You could start with the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: @Vrouvrou The wiki article got rather complicated. The key is using dominated convergence to prove $$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \int g(x,y) \mathrm d y = \int \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(x+h, y) - g(x, y)}{h} \mathrm d y.$$ A sufficient condition on bounded domain is that $g$ is continuous and $g(\cdot,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous with a constant independent of $y$

Comment: so the condition is $f_u(t,0)=cst$

Comment: @Vrouvrou It is surely sufficient. But, it might be not necessary.

Comment: how it might be not necessary ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou there might be other choice for $f_u(s,0)$.

Comment: is there a weaker condition please ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou I don't know.